# AudioKit: Fade in from AKOperationGenerator

Tags: swift, audiokit

Is there a way to fade in a sound from an AKOperationGenerator?

E.g. in the code below .start() begins at full amplitude with a click.

```
let whiteNoiseGenerator = AKOperationGenerator { _ in

    let white = AKOperation.whiteNoise()
    return white
}


AudioKit.output = whiteNoiseGenerator
whiteNoiseGenerator.start()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to skin this cat. I'll give you a couple:

One would be to wrap the noise generator in an AKBooster:

```
let volumeControl = AKBooster(whiteNoiseGenerator)
volumeControl.gain = 0
volumeControl.rampTime = 1 // number of seconds to fade in/out
AudioKit.output = volumeControl
AudioKit.start() // Don't forget this, I assume you just didn't paste it in
whiteNoiseGenerator.start() // nothing will be heard
```

Then starting and stopping the sound will just be done by setting

```
volumeControl.gain = 1 // or 0 for stopping
```

Alternatively, I know you wanted to know how to do this in the context of an operation, so you can do that by giving your operation parameters of gain and portamento time:

```
let whiteNoiseGenerator = AKOperationGenerator { parameters in

    let white = AKOperation.whiteNoise() * parameters[0].portamento(halfDuration: parameters[1])
    return white
}

whiteNoiseGenerator.parameters = [0,0.1] // first number is gain, second is portamento time
AudioKit.output = whiteNoiseGenerator
AudioKit.start()
whiteNoiseGenerator.start()
```

And then, when you want to turn on the noise do this:

```
whiteNoiseGenerator.parameters[0] = 1
```

you will get a smooth variation to full volume over 0.1 seconds.

HTH!

Comment: 2nd solution works great thanks. For the first, I think you mean: volumeControl.gain = 1 // or 0 for stopping

Comment: Another approach I'm exploring is to use incorporate MPVolumeView but this seems to crash the app when switching between AKOperationGenerators.

Comment: You have to be careful about that. Ideally you just have one audio engine that starts and stops the generators as necessary rather than starting and stopping AudioKit. It can be a delicate balance.